# App keeps re-rendering when setting state in promise using useState in React

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I'd like to make a call to a rest endpoint, retrieve an array of items and display them in the page.

```js
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

axios
    .get("https://reqres.in/api/users")
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      setUsers(response.data.data);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // handle error
      console.log(error);
    });
```

```
return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {users.length &&
            users.map(user => (
              <tr key={user.id}>
                <td>{user.first_name}</td>
                <td>{user.last_name}</td>
                <td>{user.email}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          {users.length === 0 && "Loading..."}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
```

However, the app keeps re-rendering constantly. I tried to place the ajax call inside a `useEffect` callback, but it had no... effect

Here is a link to a sandbox with the code: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-tree-zzcoq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move your api call inside `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios
    .get("https://reqres.in/api/users")
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      setUsers(response.data.data);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // handle error
      console.log(error);
    });
}, [])
```

[Updated sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/red-lake-zbbvi)

Comment: Why is there an empty array as a second param to the useEffect?

Comment: It means that the callback inside `useEffect` will be called only once when component renders.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is clear. Axios.get is called every time when the component is rendered. To prevent this, we can call the Axios.get inside the useState call.
Here is my solution.

```js
function App() {

  const [renderCounter, setRenderCounter] = useState(0);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(() => {
    axios
    .get("https://reqres.in/api/users")
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      setRenderCounter(renderCounter + 1);
      setUsers(response.data.data);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // handle error
      console.log(error);
    });
    return [];
  });

  
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Renders: {renderCounter}</div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {users.length &&
            users.map(user => (
              <tr key={user.id}>
                <td>{user.first_name}</td>
                <td>{user.last_name}</td>
                <td>{user.email}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          {users.length === 0 && "Loading..."}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```